# Convert Object to JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

`jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}')` converts string representation to object
but I want the reverse. Object is to be converted to JSON string
I got a link http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/convert-javascript-object-to-json.html
but it need to have json2.js. Does jQuery have a native method to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932686/how-to-alert-json-file-data-from-javascript

Answer (score 191, accepted):

jQuery does only make some regexp checking before calling the native browser method `window.JSON.parse()`. If that is not available, it uses `eval()` or more exactly `new Function()` to create a Javascript object.

The opposite of `JSON.parse()` is `JSON.stringify()` which serializes a Javascript object into a string. jQuery does not have functionality of its own for that, you have to use the browser built-in version or `json2.js` from http://www.json.org

`JSON.stringify()` is available in all major browsers, but to be compatible with older browsers you still need that fallback.

Comment: this may be helpful: `var theObject = (typeof data == "string") ? jQuery.parseJSON(data) : data;`

Comment: @tekretic: I hope you're trolling. Chrome implements the `JSON` host object since day 1.

Comment: @jAndy: Oh wow, sorry. Not trolling but OH so wrong. 

Turns out native JSON support was [added to WebKit in mid 2009](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20031), making it supported since Chrome 3.0. 

My previous, totaly inaccurate comment was based on a half of [this outdated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364842/json-is-not-defined-chrome) combined with the CMS I'm working on at the moment which actually replaces window.JSON with its own library, meaning `JSON.stringify()` isn't defined. Quite a fail on all counts.

Comment: For those interested, here's [a nice chart of native JSON support in different browsers](http://caniuse.com/json).

Comment: @jAndy: dont confuse me; : JSON.stringify 'serialises' an object, please say that its just a mistake

Comment: @halfbit Serialization is taking an object and writing it out as a string.  Deserialization is taking a string and converting it into an object.

Answer (score 12):

Also useful is Object.toSource() for debugging purposes, where you want to show the object and its properties for debugging purposes. This is a generic Javascript (not jQuery) function, however it only works in "modern" browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Convert JavaScript object to json data

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = $("form").serializeArray(); // Create array of object
  var jsonConvertedData = JSON.stringify(formData);  // Convert to json
  consol.log(jsonConvertedData);
});
```

You can validate json data using http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use the excellent jquery-Json plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Makes it easy to convert to and from Json objects.

Comment: Please recommend SPL methods over add-on logic libraries.

Comment: SPL = Standard PHP Library. Guess in this case is would be SJL (standard javascript library).

Comment: The question is about jQuery & Javascript. It nothing to do with PHP, PHP libraries or SPL.

Comment: standard libraries are standard libraries; don't matter the language. My point being it is better to recommend a solution that teaches the language over 'use this plugin' syndrome.

Comment: sure but why reinvent the wheel? he could always look at the source code of the plugin.

Comment: Exactly, why reinvent the wheel...use the standard abilities of a language over a 'plugin' but I digress.

Comment: How about adding your own answer instead of hijacking everybody else's? If you don't think people should use libraries, or that libraries have no merit then you are in the wrong industry haha.

Comment: jAndy recommended the (imho) best answer JSON.stringify().