# Querying JSON output. (From MySQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

I'm working on a calendar roster system for work. Unfortunately most solutions/plugins aren't ideal for what I want.

Anywho, what I was wondering is if it possible to select a value from an array output in JSON format, based on multiple criteria. I am using jQuery

to put it fairly generically (haven't started coding it yet):

```
<for each cell>
--<find ['number_of_slots'] in JSONarray where ['AppointmentDate'] = "02/02/12" && ['salespoint'] = 1 && ['AppointmentTime] = '10AM'>
--<if no results>
-----<fill cell with 'x'>
--<else>
-----<fill cell with ['number_of_slots']
--<end if>
```

Or am I better off making an MySQL query for each cell? Just seems to be quite a number of transactions, that's all.

As always, any help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Is manipulating the data as javascript object than parsing it to jSon acceptable?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure how I'd accomplish that.
The JSON is provided by PHP from a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

If manipulating the data as javascript object than parsing it back to jSon is acceptable:

Parse it to js object:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Parse it <strike>back to jSon</strike> to String:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Parse to jSon issue discussed
[Convert Object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904269/convert-object-to-json-string)

Not the answer to your question but a solution with jQuery, though

Comment: Well if I'm able to replicate a MySQL SELECT statment on that object, then, sure. Do you know if this would be the case?

Comment: Well, you should be able to.
Since the jsToJson Parser works in a certain way you can always manipulate the js input in a manner that you reach the desired output.