# Convert Array to Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)
>   [Convert Object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904269/convert-object-to-json-string)

I want to  convert array to json object in js or jquery.
     Is there any function is available or lib

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In modern browsers you can simply use `JSON.stringify(someJSObject)` to convert any JavaScript object (that includes arrays) to a JSON string.

To ensure it also works in less modern browsers, include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js on your page.

Answer (score 17):

How about

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

Comment: Great, if the user has a browser modern enough to support it.

Comment: yes, your browser can't be 3 years old... If it is, it's not that difficult to create custom object->json parser

Comment: IE6 has about 1% share, so I don't really have to care about it. And I thought that IE8 has JSON support (with maybe some issues with callbacks).

Comment: I said IE 8 supports it. IE 7 doesn't. Between IE 7 and IE 8 you are talking about more than one in twenty users. (Usual provisos about browser stats apply).

Comment: Well from "you need to hit IE 8 before it supports JSON" I understood that you mean IE8 doesn't support. Anyway, IE7 is 5 years old. I really don't see point in supporting such old browser (unless you developing some custom internal application for some company). Modern games don't run on old PCs, and web applications/pages are becoming similar. Anyway, let's not flame :)

Comment: "Hit" not "Pass". The point in support an old browser is that more than 1 in 20 people use it. That's a *lot* of customers / advert views / whatever.