# how can i transform data to json type where data includes variables?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Even my code works to pass value with ajax.I still want to transform data to json type then pass it to ajax,like this:

```
{"name":"test"}
```

and now data is like this below:

```
var data = {
            'name': $("#name").val()
        }
```

how can I get json? thank you for your answer!

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? You can just pass the variable as is to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: I know this~ and i just wanna have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

kindly refer this link

[How to create JSON string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963693/how-to-create-json-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```