# how to read typical json data using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all i am working on json data to show it on mobile apps  how to read this type of json data 
'limitvalue'

previously im sending all data to one object and reading but now it is not understandable how to read 
can some suggest me with some sample example.

here is the json data that we want to use in that we need to show CoverageName and limitvalue.

```
 [{"CoverageName":"Business Income"},{"CoverageName":"Employee Benefits Liability","Values":
{"Employee Benefits Liability Limit":{"limitvalue":"1000000"}}},{"CoverageName":"Extended Period
ofIndemnity"},{"CoverageName":"Limited Blanket Additional Insured"},{"CoverageName":"Non Owned 
Including Hired Automobile Coverage"},{"CoverageName":"Per Location Aggregate"},
{"CoverageName":"Tenant Legal Liability","Values":{"Tenant Legal Liability Limit"
:{"limitvalue":"100000"}}},{"CoverageName":"Employee Dishonesty","Values":{"Employee Dishonesty  
Limit":{"limitvalue":"5000"}}},{"CoverageName":"Supplemental Payments_Third Party Attorneys
 Fees"},{"CoverageName":"Employment Practices Liability","Values":{"EPLI Limit":  
{"limitvalue":"100000"},"EPLI Deductible":{"deductablevalue":"2500"}}},{"CoverageName":"Included
Coverage Package"},{"CoverageName":"Business Owners","Values":{"General Liability Aggregate
Limit":{"limitvalue":"2000000"},"General Liability Occurrence Limit":
{"limitvalue":"1000000"},"Total Building Limit":{"limitvalue":"0.0"},"Total Contents Limit":
{"limitvalue":"0.0"},"Property Deductible":{"deductablevalue":"100000"}}}]
```

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932686/how-to-alert-json-file-data-from-javascript

Comment: hi,Tony,JSON.parse will not work for him,because his data is a json array

Comment: we can read "CoverageName" but  we need to read "limitvalue" ,"deductablevalue"

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery $.getJSON

```
  $.getJSON('your_json_file', function(data) {                            

          answers=data.CoverageName;//Objects of your file like CoverageName              

        alert(JSON.stringify(answers)); //object name to string           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first get this data in object then this code will help you

```
var jsonData = yourData;
var table = "table";
for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++)
{
    table += "<tr><td>"+jsonData[i].CoverageName+"</td><td>"+jsonData[i].Values+"</td><tr>";
}
table += "</table>";

$('#yourDivID').append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.parseJSON()

```
 Example  data_arr=$.parseJSON(data); //data json array
```