# Trying to get json info with getJSON (jquery)

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

Im trying to use this api that gives me a json. But I can't display any info. I got this code in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").click(function(){
      var title = $("#words").val().replace(/\s/g,"+");
      var url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q="+title+"&apikey=ng6gbx7vdpwmyfwd7vp5g799" + "?callback=?";

   $.getJSON(url, null, function(data){           
           alert(data.total);

   });
  });
});
```

Why? I have no idea.

Comment: Are you returning total from the api?

Comment: May be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932686/how-to-alert-json-file-data-from-javascript

Comment: set in stead of alert(data.total), Console.log(data) to see whats in your data object

Comment: What is the output of `alert(data.total);`?

Comment: alert(data.total) doesn't return anything.

Comment: console.log(data) neither

Comment: using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932686/how-to-alert-json-file-data-from-javascript it returns me "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API only supports JSONp. so you need to do the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        var title = $("#words").val().replace(/\s/g,"+");
        var url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q="+title+"&apikey=ng6gbx7vdpwmyfwd7vp5g799";

         $.ajax(url, {
             dataType: "jsonp",
             success: function(data){           
                 alert(data.total);
             }  
         });
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpTm3/

updated fiddle with `alert`: http://jsfiddle.net/rpTm3/1/

Comment: It's because browser can download JSON only from your domain. 
You need jsonp workaround to download json files from other servers.
Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Also cause they don't have a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` tag in the headers.