# Use a for-in loop to get data from a JSON object which is not an array

Tags: arrays, json, undefined, for-in-loop

I'm trying to loop through the results of a JSON response and get the title of each article, however my hosting company mentioned the returned object is not an array, so I can't loop through the articles.

Currently it gives me an undefined on the length of the amount of articles.

How can I loop through the articles and get their titles?

I tried everything below, and finally read somewhere I could use a for-in loop.
So I was checking out this example here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_for_in

However, I have no idea how to apply this loop on my data to get just the articles and then loop through these and get their properties.

**JSON RESPONSE**

```
{
    "blog": {
        "id": "1464",
        "comments": true,
        "url": "blogs\/magazine",
        "rss": "blogs\/magazine.rss",
        "title": "Taj Magazine",
        "articles": {
            "3748": {
                "id": 3748,
                "image": 7442452,
                "url": "blogs\/magazine\/foodies-walhalla-2",
                "title": "Foodies Walhalla 2",
                "author": "",
                "author_url": false,
                "summary": "dit is de samenvatting tekst",
                "content": "dit is het hele artikel",
                "date": "2013-11-13 13:54:00",
                "comments": [],
                "comments_count": 0,
                "tags": {
                    "foodies-walhalla": {
                        "id": "9794",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/foodies-walhalla",
                        "title": "Foodies Walhalla",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "magazine": {
                        "id": "9744",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/magazine",
                        "title": "magazine",
                        "count": "6"
                    }
                }
            },
            "3747": {
                "id": 3747,
                "image": 7442441,
                "url": "blogs\/magazine\/foodies-walhalla-1",
                "title": "Foodies Walhalla 1",
                "author": "",
                "author_url": false,
                "summary": "f df gdsfg",
                "content": "dsfgsdfgdf sdfg",
                "date": "2013-11-13 11:22:00",
                "comments": [],
                "comments_count": 0,
                "tags": {
                    "foodies-walhalla": {
                        "id": "9794",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/foodies-walhalla",
                        "title": "Foodies Walhalla",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "magazine": {
                        "id": "9744",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/magazine",
                        "title": "magazine",
                        "count": "6"
                    }
                }
            },
            "3744": {
                "id": 3744,
                "image": 7442425,
                "url": "blogs\/magazine\/beauty-artikel-2",
                "title": "Beauty artikel 2",
                "author": "",
                "author_url": false,
                "summary": "beauty article 2",
                "content": "dfg sfg sdfg sdfgd gdsf df gsdf gdsf g",
                "date": "2013-11-13 11:21:00",
                "comments": [],
                "comments_count": 0,
                "tags": {
                    "beauty": {
                        "id": "9792",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/beauty",
                        "title": "beauty",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "healthy": {
                        "id": "9745",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/healthy",
                        "title": "healthy",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "magazine": {
                        "id": "9744",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/magazine",
                        "title": "magazine",
                        "count": "6"
                    }
                }
            },
            "3745": {
                "id": 3745,
                "image": 7442417,
                "url": "blogs\/magazine\/love-life-1",
                "title": "Love & Life 1",
                "author": "",
                "author_url": false,
                "summary": "dfgdsfgd",
                "content": "f gdf gdfgdfg dfgdsfgdsfgdsfg",
                "date": "2013-11-13 11:21:00",
                "comments": [],
                "comments_count": 0,
                "tags": {
                    "love-life": {
                        "id": "9793",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/love-life",
                        "title": "love & life",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "magazine": {
                        "id": "9744",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/magazine",
                        "title": "magazine",
                        "count": "6"
                    }
                }
            },
            "3746": {
                "id": 3746,
                "image": 7442388,
                "url": "blogs\/magazine\/love-life-2",
                "title": "Love & Life 2",
                "author": "",
                "author_url": false,
                "summary": "dfkjghksdjfh gdskfjdj sdlkjfhdjfghdjklfsdfkjhg df gd ghdkjsfhgkjsd fg lkjdshklgdfh kjds glkjsdh kljdsfh",
                "content": "dfkjghksdjfh gdskfjdj sdlkjfhdjfghdjklfsdfkjhg df gd ghdkjsfhgkjsd fg lkjdshklgdfh kjds glkjsdh kljdsfh",
                "date": "2013-11-13 11:21:00",
                "comments": [],
                "comments_count": 0,
                "tags": {
                    "love-life": {
                        "id": "9793",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/love-life",
                        "title": "love & life",
                        "count": "2"
                    },
                    "magazine": {
                        "id": "9744",
                        "url": "blogs\/magazine\/tagged\/magazine",
                        "title": "magazine",
                        "count": "6"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "url": "http:\/\/taj-ringen.webshopapp.com\/blogs\/magazine\/?format=json",
        "method": "get",
        "ssl": false,
        "get": {
            "format": "json"
        },
        "post": [],
        "device": {
            "platform": "windows",
            "type": "webkit",
            "mobile": false
        }
    },
    "template": "pages\/blog.rain",
    "renderer": "json"
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<div id="loadstatus"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var newresult = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://taj-ringen.webshopapp.com/blogs/magazine/?format=json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (mydata) {
            console.log('load successful');
            console.log('mydata.blog.articles.length: ' + mydata.blog.articles.length);  //'undefined' error
            for (var i = 0; i < mydata.blog.articles.length; i++) {
                newresult += mydata.blog.articles[i].title;
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

I also had a look at this post: [Convert Object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904269/convert-object-to-json-string)

**tried the `jQuery.parseJSON` function**

```
        console.log(mydata);
        var tmp = jQuery.parseJSON(mydata);
        console.log(tmp);        
        console.log('tmp.blog.articles.length: ' + tmp.blog.articles.length);
```

But there I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` on line jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4

**tried the `$.map` function**

```
        var array = $.map(mydata, function (e) {
            return [$.map(e, function (v) {
                return v;
            })];
        });
        console.log(array);

        console.log('tmp.blog.articles.length: ' + array.blog.articles.length);
```

Here I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '14' in pages/blog.rain` on line `jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4`

What I'm trying to to is convert the object that is returned by the site and be able to loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the article object, pulling out the keys associated with each article using the method described in the below post:

[How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

You could also use the following loop:

```
for(var article in blog.articles) {
    console.log(blog.articles[article].title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But using your method I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`, probably because the id of the article actually holds the property title etc. How can I alter your statement to access the title properties of all articles?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to pull each article out of the array in which they are contained. Updated the code above, which hopefully should do the trick.