# Django Rest Framework: Custom JSON Serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am struggling to figure out how to write a custom serializer in DRF to parse a complex JSON data structure that is being passed to an endpoint. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "new",
    "site": "US",
    "data": {
        "settings": [],
        "meta": {
            "meta1":{}
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my backend code:

```
# views.py
class SaveData(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        site = request.POST.get('site')
        data = request.POST.get('data')
```

But `data` always returns `None`. On closer inspection into the `request` object, the incoming JSON looks like this:

```
# POST attribute of request object
'name' = 'new'
'site' = 'US'
'data[settings][0] = ''
'data[meta][meta1][] = ''
```

Basically it looks like the nested JSON objects associated with the `data` key are not getting properly serialized into Python `dict` and `list` objects. I've been looking for examples of custom DRF serializers but most of the ones I've found have been for serializing Django models, but I don't need to do that. The incoming data does not directly map to my models; instead I need to do some processing before I save any of the data.

Does anyone have any advice on a custom serializer that would properly convert the `data` JSON into proper Python objects? I started with this but it throws an exception (`When a serializer is passed a 'data' keyword argument you must call '.is_valid()' before attempting to access the serialized '.data' representation.
You should either call '.is_valid()' first, or access '.initial_data' instead.`). Here is my code with the custom serializer I created:

```
# serializers.py
class SaveDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    site = serializers.CharField()
    data = serializers.DictField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return dict(**validated_data)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by converting the JS object to JSON when passing it to `$.ajax`, which then DRF was able to correctly parse into Python objects. Here's a snippet of the jQuery I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/endpoint',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
    done: function(data) {}
    ...
})
```

Note though that jQuery will default to `x-www-urlencoded` as the `Content-Type` if you don't specify anything. Since I'm using the `JSON.stringify()` method to explicitly convert the `ajaxData` object to a JSON string the `Content-Type` needed to be explicitly set as well.

I got the idea from this SO answer: [Convert Object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904269/convert-object-to-json-string)

Of course, this doesn't really answer my original question, but this is another solution that is simpler and works like I wanted. By doing this I didn't have to create any custom serializers, but I did have to modify my API view like so:

```
class SaveData(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.data.get('name')
        site = request.data.get('site')
        data = request.data.get('data')
```

After doing this the expected object types are returned

```
>>> type(name)
str
>>> type(site)
str
>>> type(data)
dict
```